# Awk Delete Rows based on Duplicate fields

Tags: awk

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
Input 

Cat   2 1 aa
Dog   1 0 aa 
Dog   1 2 aa
Cat   2 7 aa
Mouse 0 0 aa
Cat   1 5 
Dog   4 3
.     . .
.     . .
.     . .
Cat   1 5 
Dog   4 3
Cat   6 9 bb
Dog   3 1 bb 
Dog   3 6 bb
Cat   6 4 bb
Mouse 0 0 bb
```

With this dataset I want to do the following:

- If column 4 is blank, print the line.
- If Column 4 is not blank, print only the first occurrence of the record with each combination of column 1 and column 4.

  Output
  Cat   2 1 aa
  Dog   1 0 aa
  Mouse 0 0 aa
  Cat   1 5
  Dog   4 3
  .     . .
  .     . .
  .     . .
  Cat   1 5
  Dog   4 3
  Cat   6 4 bb
  Dog   3 1 bb
  Mouse 0 0 bb

Note that here: "Cat 2 1 aa" is the first record with column 1=cat and column 4=aa, so it is printed. "cat 1 5 aa" is not printed since we already have a record with column 1=cat and column 4=aa.

Comment: Try a combination of sort + uniq + awk .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '$4 == "" || !a[$1,$4]++' input
```

Results:

```
Cat   2 1 aa
Dog   1 0 aa 
Mouse 0 0 aa
Cat   1 5 
Dog   4 3
.     . .
.     . .
.     . .
Cat   1 5 
Dog   4 3
Cat   6 9 bb
Dog   3 1 bb 
Mouse 0 0 bb
```

Comment: You made that a very easy! Nice one! :)